# How to explode string with zip code and town including diacritic by php

Tags: php, explode

I want to explode string with a zip code and town, for example I have the below data:

- 60200 Praha
- 73000 Valašské Meziříčí
- 641 02 Nové Město nad Metují
  etc.

Now, I need a variable `$zipcode` with the zipcode from the string and a `$town` variable with town name from the string. Example:

- $zipcode = 60200, $town = Praha
- $zipcode = 73000 , $town = Valašské Meziříčí
- $zipcode = 641 02, $town = Nové Město nad Metují

Comment: (What *is* your problem, *what* is your question?)

Comment: Make an attempt and share it. Show where you are going wrong or a stuck.

Comment: Make more readable

Answer (score 0):

The regexp could be `^(\d{3} ?\d{2}) (.*)$`

```
$inputs = [
    '60200 Praha',
    '73000 Valašské Meziříčí',
    '641 02 Nové Město nad Metují'
];

foreach ($inputs as $row) {
    preg_match('~^(\d{3} ?\d{2}) (.*)$~', $row, $matches);
    print_r($matches);

    // $matches[1] - zipcode
    // $matches[2] - city
}
```